# Show discrepancies between two SQL tables

Tags: sql, database

I've got two tables (Workday and Portal) that are almost identical, however Workday table gets updated by HR and the Workday table gets updated via an API.

I would like to write an SQL query that shows when a field has been modified in Workday table (reference table) and a discrepancy has been created in Portal table.

All the joins that I've tried returned all the data from both tables instead of filtering out the fields that are alike.

How can I join both tables and only return discrepancies?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a tag for the database you are using, and an explanation of what *you* mean by "discrepancy".

Comment: "Workday table gets updated by HR and the Workday table gets updated via an API" : I guess one of the two tables should be "portal"... the 2nd one ?

Comment: Hi webofmars, the second table is called Workday.

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you want the data from table where workday had changed some data. You can use the `minus` set operator as follows:

```
Select * -- or you can use specific column
  From workday_table
Minus
Select * 
  From identical_table;
```